# How do I see randomly generated number in Java?

Tags: java, android, logging, random

I generated random number in java but I wanna see which number is generated in the program log so how do I do that?

```
import java.util.*;

Random rand = new Random();
int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;

Log.i("Generated Number: " , n.toString());
```

I tried this but it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the string value of the integer worked.

```
Log.i("Generated Number: ", String.valueOf(n));
```

Comment: You should mark this answer as the solution. You could also have used `Integer.toString(n)` in place of `String.valueOf(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

What logger are you using? 
It looks like you are ignoring parameter. Try

```
Log.i("Generated Number: {}", n);
```

or just concatinate string and number

```
Log.i("Generated Number: " + n);
```

Comment: It showed an error "Wrong 2nd Argument type. Found:' int', required: 'java.lang.String'  "

**Solved** 

 `Log.i("Generated Number: ", String.valueOf(n));`

Comment: OP is using the Android API. Neither of these suggestions works for that. The first argument is a log tag. The second should be a string to be logged. An optional third argument of type `Throwable` can be used to log an exception and stack trace.